# Please explain how point doubling and point addition works in Elliptic curves with calculations in basic terms.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Please explain how point doubling and point addition works in basic terms with calculations. Since I am new to this topic, I am unable to get the gist of it.

Comment: A first idea you get from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) especially in the section about the group law.

Comment: I have, but it's kinda complex